# Installing software center in Lubuntu running via Virtual Box?

Tags: software-center, lubuntu

Can anyone tell me why I cannot install the software center in Lubuntu running via virtual box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the Ubuntu Software Center in Lubuntu open **Synaptic Package Manager** from *System Tools* and install the **software-center** package.

[image]

This will install the Software Center to *System Tools* menu.

Comment: Thanks....this did the magic, but I couldnt find the software I wanted to install (libreoffice :))

Comment: LibreOffice is definitely there. Search for "libreoffice" in the Software Center, or in Synaptic.

Comment: Make sure the adequate software sources (main, universe, multiverse, restricted) are enabled. If you want to be sure you can find everything available through the Software Center or Synaptic, enable all sources.