# lubuntu can't start softwares

Tags: lubuntu, downloads

I've just downloaded Lubuntu 14.04 and each software I download, I don't know how to open it. For example I just downloaded UNetbootin, but when I double click on it, it won't start. Same for others like Wine. I downloaded UNetbootin from the official site and the Linux version. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Try installing UNetbootin from the official repo, i.e. install it from Lubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: The file you want to double click, what is it's name? Especially the filetype is interesting, like .deb or .exe or whatever you downloaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing software center in Lubuntu running via Virtual Box?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/115472/installing-software-center-in-lubuntu-running-via-virtual-box) (That VirtualBox is being used there is not relevant to the solution, at least not to its applicability here. We might even edit that question to remove VirtualBox from the title--particularly if we end up merging answers.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably (my guess) that you did not download the correct file. But let's do this step by step. Don't worry, it's not as much as it looks like. Note that I'm using the german translation and translated them myself back to english to give the following instructions:

## Installing unetbootin (or other applications) in lubuntu.

- Click on the start button to show the **start menu**.
- Click on **"System tools"** and then **"Lubuntu Software Center"**.
  *Note: To create a shortcut to the software center on the desktop, make a right click on it's icon and click on "Add to desktop".*
- In the Software Center, click on **All**.
- Type **"unetbootin"** to find it, **double click** on it.
- Click on the bottom right on **"Add to ..."**.
- Click at the top on the button on the right with the question mark.
- Review what will be installed and click on **"Install Packages"**

## Install applications from downloaded files

In case you want or have to install from a downloaded file, you should always choose a linux download, while you should always prefer .deb files. Those are a bit like the setup files on windows.

To install those, yust make a double click on it. A windows will appear, providing a button named "Install Package". Click it, enter your password and the application will be installed. When it's finished successfully, you can start it from the start menu. Remember that you can create shortcuts to applications, it's really useful.

## The difference

You may wonder what the difference between downloading from the website and using the software center is. Well, the official website of an application probably offers the newest version earlier. On the other hand, the versions from the software center are more likely to work stable on your system. Also it's nice to have a software center, right?

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with Lubuntu but it seems very similar to Ubuntu and you say you double click it as if its a windows executable. Just in case that is the case, know that there are no executables in Linux and you need to go into the terminal and enter `chmod +x /path/to/file.run` to run .run files.

Edit: In response to your last comment Im not sure what the problem is because if your sure you entered the path of the file write it shouldnt return that error, what path did you enter?

Comment: Ok so i entered that string in the terminal and it says that the directory or the file does not exist, but I'm sure the path to file is right.